# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-timeout

I have a Windows Service(c#) that receives data and inserts it into DB using Entity Framework 6. Database is SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition. Both (Service and DB) are hosted on same VPS( Windows Server 2008 R2 with 4 GB RAM). The load on the server and service is too low, approx 60 records per minute.

Now intermittently I get the below error in Logs:

**Exception**:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

**Inner Exception**:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout
>   Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The
>   connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete
>   the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while
>   attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent
>   while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login]
>   initialization=0; handshake=7145; [Login] initialization=0;
>   authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=7387;  --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation
>   timed out

Any help regarding fixing this shall be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Connection String:

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=wheeltrack;UID=wheeltrack;PWD=wheeltrack; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Max Pool Size=1000;
```

Comment: You may be having serious deadlocks. SQL Trace and you will have to do some query modification. This kind of error may very well come from the order in which the tables are read/altered. Making sure that Table1 is always queried/modified before Table2 and that Table2 is queried/modified always before Table3 will likely solve your issue.